# How to allow view mode selection during content creation?

Tags: 7, nodes, display-suite, entities

We have a content type, basic page, that can be of three types

1. Publication
2. Webcast
3. Audio/Video

There is a field that based on the Basic Page type, we switch the fields that are displayed. So for when type="Audio/Video", then we display fields A-C, but if type="webcast", then we display fields D-G on the node edit page.

Based on the basic page type, the node view should display as per the type. We were thinking of using Display Suite to help control the output/rendering of the fields and have three different view modes that are consistent with the three types.

Then based on the view mode, the different fields are shown on the node/edit page and on the node/view page, then the appropriate display is used.

We are having trouble presenting the content authors the ability to change the view modes. How would we allow for the choice of view modes during the node creation process?

Comment: Why not make each: `publication, webcast, audio/video` be their own content type, instead of all being a Basic Page?

Comment: That is not the purpose of view mode. If you do want to mix the three types into one content type then use template preprocess functions and templates to control display. Else use Field Collection or Entity References to build dynamic content.